# What is the correct way to respond to a socket.io post function in sails?

Tags: socket.io, sails.js

Client side:

```
io.socket.get('/measurements', {
    id: id,
    _csrf: csrf,
}, function (resData, jwRes) {
    console.log(resData);
});
```

Server side:

```
fn: async function () {

    var measurements = [];

    if (!this.req.isSocket) {
        //error here
    } else {
        // get measurements, removed this section for readibility
        return this.res.status(200).json({
            measurements: measurements
        });
    }
}
```

This works, it returns the measurements, but it also returns the following error:

```
Error: Cannot write to response more than once
```

I think this is because Sails is sending a 200 response after my response, but I can't figure out how to override Sails' response or append the measurements to it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out sails is smarter than I thought. By trial and errror I found that I could replace:

```
return this.res.status(200).json({
        measurements: measurements
    });
```

with:

```
return ({measurements});
```

And sails does the rest.

Comment: I was about to answer this but you answered it yourself. The reason why it works is because you are probably using "[actions2](https://sailsjs.com/documentation/concepts/actions-and-controllers#?actions-2)". Actions2 are a new construct that follows the [Node Machine spec/interface](https://node-machine.org/spec/machine), where you just return the data and it handles the response for you.